# Nested Views inside a modal not showing up. (ui-router and ui-bootstrap)

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap, angular-ui-router

I'm having trouble creating a modal that responds to the application state.
From angular ui-router wiki I saw how to achieve my goal but my code is not working and I'm not figuring out why for the following reasons:

1. when application router is /sign/in the modal is launched
2. I can see the following output at my console

   `=> "about.sign"`

   `=> "about.sign.in"`
3. The 2) means that both routers and firing!
   In other words the modal should be opened `about.sign` and the template from `about.sign.in` state should be inserted on it's parent template, more precisely on  tag.

**I tried both techniques. Named ui-views and anonymous  but none worked.**

https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Frequently-Asked-Questions#how-to-open-a-dialogmodal-at-a-certain-state

```
 var app = angular.module('app.auth',
    [
      'ui.bootstrap',
      'ui.router'
    ]);

  app.config(function($stateProvider){
    $stateProvider
      .state('about',{
        url: '/',
        views:{
          'main': {
            templateUrl: 'about/about.tpl.html'
          }
        }
      })
      .state('about.sign',{
        url: '',
        onEnter: function($stateParams, $state, $modal){
          console.log('about.sign')
          var modalInstance = $modal.open({
            template:'<h1>Modal</h1><div ui-view="bar-view"></div>',
            size: 'sm',
          });
        }
      })
      .state('about.sign.in',{
        url:'sign/in',
        onEnter: function($stateParams, $state, $modal){
          console.log('about.sign.in')
        },
        views: {
          'bar-view': {
            template: 'Sign in #1'
          }
        }

      })
      .state('about.sign.up',{
        url:'sign/up',
        onEnter: function($stateParams, $state, $modal){
          console.log('about.sign.in')
        },
        views: {
          'bar-view': {
            template: 'Sign up #2'
          }
        }

      })
  }); //end of app.config
```

Am I doing something wrong with those nested views??

Comment: Did you have any luck with this? i'm facing the same issue

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I bumped into this one as well. It turns out you need to use "parent" instead of dot notation.

Here is the [plunker](http://embed.plnkr.co/DJP7sp/preview)

```
angular.module('app', ['ui.router', 'ui.bootstrap'])
  .config(['$stateProvider', '$urlRouterProvider', function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {

    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/');

    $stateProvider
      .state('view', {
        url: '',
        template: '<button class="btn btn-default" ui-sref="modal"> Modal</button> <ui-view />',
        controller: function($scope) {
        }
      })
      .state('modal', {
        //abstract: true,
        parent: 'view',
        url: '/modal',
        onEnter: ['$modal', '$state', function($modal, $state) {
            console.log('Open modal');
            $modal.open({
              template: '<button class="btn btn-danger" ui-sref="signin"> sign-in </button> <button ui-sref="signout" class="btn btn-success"> sign-out </button> <div ui-view="modal"></div>',
              backdrop: false,
              windowClass: 'right fade'
            }).result.finally(function() {
              $state.go('list');
          });
        }]
      })
      .state('signin', {
        url: '/signin',
        parent: 'modal',
        views: {
          'modal@': {
            template: '<p>sign-in</p>'
            }
          }
      })
      .state('signout', {
        url: '/signout',
        parent: 'modal',
        views: {
          'modal@': {
            template: '<p>sign-out</p>'
            }
          }
      })
    }]);
```

Comment: What does "@" stand for in `modal@`? Why not only `views: {modal: ...}` since it's named as `<div ui-view="modal">`?

Comment: you can find more information from [here](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Multiple-Named-Views#user-content-view-names---relative-vs-absolute-names) , but I think this one kinda a special case that only for modal with nested view.

Comment: I tried this, and my app would always freak out when going from my first child state to the second (in your case, analogous to switching from "signin" to "signout"). Also your plunker seems to be gone. What version of ui-router are you on? I have 0.2.13.

Comment: Ah, ok. Here's a working [plunker link](http://plnkr.co/edit/DJP7sp?p=preview). I see you're using 0.2.7. Maybe that is part of my problem...

Comment: You save my day. Tks!

Comment: Thanks for this answer it really saved my day! I just need one more thing. I need to use different controllers for each sub-state. How can I do that?

Comment: Actually I found the answer myself. To include Controller in the nested state all you have to do is write controller: 'yourcontrollername' right below the template.

Answer (score 3):

I think the accepted answer is a good one. (The trick was naming the view with `modal@` instead of just `modal` - see [the docs](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Multiple-Named-Views#view-names---relative-vs-absolute-names) for an explanation.) But I thought I'd post a more general solution, in case that helps others who come looking here with similar problems. (It took me quite a while to figure this all out.)

One notable difference with my approach is that I decided to create a controller to launch the modal, rather than using the `onEnter` hook (even though every other example I saw used `onEnter`), because `onEnter` doesn't give you access to the scope. This way, the controllers both for the modal and for the child states can inherit from the same parent scope.

Interesting caveat: the named views for the child states *cannot* reference the parent state. The modal essentially creates its own state, so in my example, `ui-view="modal"` doesn't exist within the context of the `launch_modal` state - it exists in the root unnamed template (hence why the child's view must be `modal@`, not `modal@launch_modal`).

```
registerRoutes: function($stateProvider) {
  var modal_instance = null;
  return $stateProvider.state('launch_modal', {
    url: '/',
    template: '',
    controller: [
      '$uibModal', '$state', '$scope', function($modal, $state, $scope) {
        // init scope variables that you want the modal and child states to inherit
        $scope.modal = {
          title: '',
        };

        // launch the dialog
        modal_instance = $modal.open({
          template: '<div ui-view="modal">',
          controller: 'MyModule.Controllers.DialogController',
          scope: $scope
        });

        // make sure we leave the state when the dialog closes
        return modal_instance.result['finally'](function() {
          modal_instance = null;
          if ($state.includes('launch_modal')) {
            return $state.go('^');
          }
        });
      }
    ],
    onExit: function() {
      // make sure the dialog is closed when we leave the state
      if (modal_instance != null) {
        modal_instance.close();
      }
    }
  }).state('launch_modal.child1', {
    url: '',
    views: {
      // note: doing `modal@launch_modal` won't work!
      'modal@': {
        templateUrl: "path/to/child1/template",
        controller: "MyModule.Controllers.Child1ViewController"
      }
    }
  });
}
```

Hope that helps some people!